# Azure Storage Blob BULK INSERT with inconsistent field terminators

Tags: sql, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

I am trying to work with an external vendor to my company that is sending a csv file that I need to import into various tables in our database. We have other vendors who send similar files and they always send csv files with quotation marks around every field (in case there are commas in the field). As such, I make the field terminator "," for the file, and it bulk inserts just fine since all fields will include this terminator.

The problem that I'm running into is that we have a new vendor that is unable to enclose every field in quotation marks. They are using RFC 4180, which includes quotation marks around fields that have commas, but it doesn't include quotation marks when there aren't commas. So, this leads to inconsistent field terminators when attempting to bulk insert, and I don't know of a way around it. If I make the field terminator a comma, it will split fields that have commas in them, but I similarly can't make the field terminator "," since that will not be around every field.

Any advice is welcome. I am trying to work with the vendor to send a consistent format, but, in case they can't, I'm trying to also find a workaround.

Comment: Can you add a sample of both the files(couple of rows) to understand the structure better?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot for privacy reasons. The files are IEP goals for Special Education students, and the data is all their personal information. The biggest problem is that the goal text might have commas in it. So, those fields will have quotation marks around them, but they may also contain commas

Comment: You can mask/remove the sensitive data and put some random characters instead or create some random fake records with similar structure, it will be difficult to understand the structure otherwise.